# How to perform a "find" in Matlab using multiple parameters?

Tags: matlab

I'm looking for a way to "vectorize" the following code. That is, I want to get rid of the for loop, which is taking a long time (this for loop is nested in another for loop that repeats more than 40,000 times).

```
for k=1:length
    if coords(k,1)<=4 && coords(k,2) <=8
        upperLeft(countUL,:) = coords(k,:);
        countUL=countUL+1;
    end
    if coords(k,1)>4 && coords(k,2) <=8
        upperRight(countUR,:) = coords(k,:);
        countUR=countUR+1;
    end
    if coords(k,1)>4 && coords(k,2) >8
        lowerRight(countLR,:) = coords(k,:);
        countLR=countLR+1;
    end
    if coords(k,1)<=4 && coords(k,2) >8
        lowerLeft(countLL,:) = coords(k,:);
        countLL=countLL+1;
    end
end
```

I tried at first to use the Matlab `find` function (e.g. `find(coords(k,1)<=4)`), but in my case I have two parameters that I need to "find". I tried something like `find(coords(:,1)<=4 && coords(:,2)<=8)`, but since the operands of `&&` are not scalar, this doesn't work. Any ideas on how to do this would be most appreciated!

Comment: I suggest you don't use `length` as a variable name (or maybe that was a typo)

Comment: use Matlab's FEX Consolidator? http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8354

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`&&` and `||` work only for scalar comparisons, as you've noticed. `&` and `|` work on vectors, though. Note that you don't even need `find`:

```
idxUL = coords(:,1) <= 4 & coords(:,2) <=8;
idxUR = coords(:,1) > 4 & coords(:,2) <=8;

upperLeft = coords(idxUL,:);
upperRight = coords(idxUR,:); %# etc
```

Comment: @robguinness: I implemented your proposed edit that was (IMO wrongly) rejected. Thanks for spotting this!